# Transformation of $e^{2\pi i z}$.

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, number-theory, congruences, modular-forms

I want to find the use of $q=e^{2\pi i z}$ in modular forms and combinatorics.
The question here maybe a little not specific,
and I'll explain it.

- I know that this is a exponential map，and map upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$ into a punctured disk.
  Besides, it is $\mathbb{Z}$-periodic holomorphic map. Thus, it makes modular forms which are complex functions fall into the framework of $q$-series.

However, I care about the congruent property of $q$-serises and I want to know whether there is algebraiclly convenient to change the $q$ into $e^{2\pi i z}$.
To be specific, I just want more example of the use the transformation of $q=e^{2\pi i z}$ in combinatorics. Any help will be appreciated.:)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What does "I want to know whether there is algebraiclly convenient to change the $q$ into $e^{2\pi i z}$" mean?

Comment: I may not explain my question well...
Sometimes we change $e^{2\pi i z}$ into $q$, just because it is convenient to calculate. I want to know that when dealing with $q$-series, if I change $q$ back to $e^{2\pi i z}$, is there any unexpected benifits？
Or, I just want more examples for this substitution.
Thanks for your commend. :)